# Ordering results with ActiveRecord and Postgres with has_many through statement

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have these 3 models here:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :parties, foreign_key: 'organizer_id'

  has_many :invitations, foreign_key: 'attendee_id'
end

class Party < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organizer, class_name: 'User'

    has_many :invitations
    has_many :attendees, through: :invitations
end

class Invitation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :party
  belongs_to :attendee, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :inviter, class_name: 'User'
end
```

I want to get all attendees for a specific party and sort them by those who invited the most people.

How do I do this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of possible solution:

### Dirty one

```
party.attendees.joins(:invitations).select('parties.*', 'COUNT(DISTINCT invitations.id) as invitation_count').group('parties.id').order('invitation_count')
```

Pros: might work

Cons: This is ugly, does not explain itself and you will end up with an extremely hard to query relation. Rather avoid.

### Slightly cleaner

Sort it on the application level:

```
party.attendees.includes(:invitations).sort_by {|att| att.inivtaions.to_a.size }
```

Pros: It is more clear what you're doing

Cons: Returns non-querable array instead of relation. Still need explanation why you're calling `to_a` (to avoid N+1 problem).

### The cleanest

Add an extra column `invitations_count` to attendees table, and add `counter_cache: true` to the `belongs_to :attendee` in your Invitation model. Profit!

```
party.attendees.order(:invitations_count)
```

Pros: Nice and self-explanatory. No need to load invitations from the database. Easily querable association.

Cons: You need to update all the records' counter_cache before you start using it:

```
Attendees.includes(:invitations).each { |att| att.invitation_count = att.invitation.to_a.size }
```

After this, rails will take care of holding the column in sync with a number of associated with attendee inivtations.

Comment: Great answer! Thx for explaining in details!

Comment: Which solution did you tired?